# Fewest operations for Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I currently am adding elements in descending order to a Binary Search Tree. With inserting the `TreeNodes` in the Binary Search Tree, the approach is standard with using recursion:

```
private void insert(TreeNode paramTreeNode1, TreeNode paramTreeNode2)
{
  this.operations += 1; 
  if (paramTreeNode2.getData() < paramTreeNode1.getData())
  {
    if (paramTreeNode1.getLeft() == null) 
    {
      paramTreeNode1.setLeft(paramTreeNode2);
    } 
    else 
    {
      insert(paramTreeNode1.getLeft(), paramTreeNode2); // recursive 
    }
  }
  else if (paramTreeNode1.getRight() == null) 
  {
    paramTreeNode1.setRight(paramTreeNode2);
  } 
  else 
  {
    insert(paramTreeNode1.getRight(), paramTreeNode2); //recursive
  }
}
```

However, this method current has >2000 number of operations. What's a smarter approach when inserting `TreeNodes` in descending order of a `BST` to reduce the total number operations?

Comment: This isn't clear.  Are you saying that you have a tree-depth of 2000?

Comment: No, the tree-depth is 45, and the number of times `insert()` has been called is more than 2000. I was thinking that there must be a more efficient way to write my code so that it doesn't have so many operations

Comment: use some tree balancing algorithm like red black tree or avl tree.